# Pivot navigation page via accelerometer error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivot, accelerometer

```
  void OnAccelerometerReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs args)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                 {
                     if (args.X > 1.0f)
                     {

                         if (contentPivot != null)
                         {
                             if (contentPivot.SelectedIndex >= contentPivot.Items.Count - 1) contentPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
                             contentPivot.SelectedIndex++;
                         }

                     }

                     if (args.X < -1.0f)
                     {

                         if (contentPivot != null)
                         {
                             if (contentPivot.SelectedIndex >= contentPivot.Items.Count - 1) contentPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
                             contentPivot.SelectedIndex--;
                         }

                     }



                 });
        }
```

I'm getting the error message "SelectedIndex." It is indicated at the `contentPivot.SelectedIndex--;` line.

The aim of this code is to allow the user to navigate to the next pivot page when I tilt it side ways.

Correct my codes if i'm really wrong.

Comment: sorry about the messiness, i meant no harm.

Comment: there is an Edit link under the question.

Comment: Dispatcher.Begin(() =>
            {
                if (args.X > 0.5f)
                {
                    contentPivot.SelectedIndex++;

                }

            });

'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'Begin' and no extension method 'Begin' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' could be found.

I've got this error, with the Dispatcher.begin underlined in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have permission, it sounds like you haven't enabled the `Sensor` capability. In your `Solution`, go to the `Properties` folder and open `WMAppManifest.xml`. Then inside the `<Capabilities>` tag, add this:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
```

(Credits goes to keyboardP for the solution)Edited once more:

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>

```
            {
                if (args.X > 0.5f)
                {

                    if (contentPivot!= null)
                    {
                        if (contentPivot.SelectedIndex >= contentPivot.Items.Count - 1) contentPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        contentPivot.SelectedIndex++;
                    }  

                }
            })
```

Comment: I've got that code in my WMAppManifest.xml. But i'm still getting that error. Maybe the codes I type is wrong? I'm not sure whether contentPivot.SelectedIndex++; actually means navigating  of pivot page. What i'm intending to do is when the user tilts the phone, the pivot page will be navigated to the next pivot page.

Comment: Could you post the actual error message? The `contentPivot.SelectedIndex++` should work fine, it must be something else.

Comment: "invalid cross-thread access." - This is the error message I'm getting.

Comment: That means you're trying to adjust the UI component from a background thread. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @user804233 - I've added a very basic error check to make sure that if the `selectedindex` value is greater than the number of pivotitems, it loops round. You can expand on this.

Comment: sorry about the previous deleted comment, i believe i have to change the e.X to args.X. My bad.

Comment: thannks for the help keyboard P

Comment: @keyboardP - if i tilt the phone to the left, it will go navigate to the right page instead. And when i tilt the phone to the right, it will navigate insanely like 5 to 6 pages across to the right. How do i go about this problem?

Comment: @lala - The reason it's going to the right is because you're using `selectedIndex++`. Instead, you can use `selectedIndex--` when the user tilts to the left. (Play around with the numbers to see detect which way the user is tilting). The reason it's moving fast is because the accelerometer is sensitive. There are various things you could do. For example, handle the `contentPivot's` LoadedPivotItem event. In this event, stop the accelerometer and start a timer (a second or so interval). When the timer interval event is fired, start the accelerometer again.

Comment: @keyboardP

Thanks a million, you're indeed a great help! Now could you teach me how to give you rep points etc.? You, deserve it!

Comment: @lala - No probs :) For rep, you can press the `up arrow` next to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @keyboardP - i'm getting the error message when i tilt my phone, i've edited the codes above to show you my code. The error message i've got is SelectedIndex.

Comment: @lala - You need to add a lower boundary. My guess is that `SelectedIndex--` is going below zero and you can't have an index below zero in PivotItems. Try `
                        if (contentPivot.SelectedIndex <= 0) contentPivot.SelectedIndex = contentPivot.Items.Count-1;
                        contentPivot.SelectedIndex--;
`

Comment: @keyboardP - Now tilting the left works. I can't solve the multi navigation page thingy, but no matter, thanks for the help. I've met 1 of the criteria.